# Step through 2 temp tables compare to table

Tags: t-sql, select, sql-like

I have a SP that is supposed to compare 2 temp tables generated from a function to another table.  My issue is that instead of stepping through each temp table it goes through both at the same time.  I am not sure how to write the code to step through each table one at a time to get the desired results.

```
    DROP PROCEDURE uspJudgments;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE uspJudgments 
@fullName varchar(100), @fullName1 varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT *
INTO #tmpFullname
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@fullName, ',')

SELECT *
INTO #tmpFullname1
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@fullName1, ',')

SELECT *
FROM #tmpFullName

SELECT *
FROM #tmpFullName1

DECLARE @MaxRownum int
SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(ItemNumber) FROM #tmpFullname)

DECLARE @Iter int
SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(ItemNumber) FROM #tmpFullname)

DECLARE @MaxRownum1 int
SET @MaxRownum1 = (SELECT MAX(ItemNumber) FROM #tmpFullname1)

DECLARE @Iter1 int
SET @Iter1 = (SELECT MIN(ItemNumber) FROM #tmpFullname1)

DECLARE @Name varchar(25)
DECLARE @Name1 varchar(25)


WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum AND @iter1 <= @Maxrownum1

BEGIN

    SET @Name = (SELECT Item FROM #tmpFullname WHERE ItemNumber = @Iter)   
    SET @Name1 = (SELECT Item FROM #tmpFullname1 WHERE ItemNumber = @Iter1)   
    SELECT *
    --INTO #tmpDefSelect
    FROM defendants_ALL 
    WHERE combined_name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' AND combined_name LIKE '%' + @Name1 + '%';

    SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
    SET @Iter1 = @Iter1 + 1
END

END


DROP TABLE #tmpFullname
DROP TABLE #tmpFullname1

EXEC uspJudgments @fullName = 'grein,smit', @fullName1 = 'joh,jon,j.'
```

I need to get ALL results for grein -- joh, jon, j. AND smit, joh, jon, j.

Currently the above code only returns grein joh AND smit, jon..  In our database that returns no results for the first combination and 38 results for jonathon smith and jon smith.  How do I properly step through each temp table to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get the two combinations `grein joh` and `smith jon` because of the way you are iterating through `@Iter` and `@iter1`.  You increment both of them at the same time.  You need a nested loop like this:

```
declare @start_val integer = @iter1

while @Iter <= MaxRownum
begin

  set @iter1 = @start_val

  while @iter1 <= @Maxrownum1
  begin

    set @Name = ...
    set @Name1 = ...

    ...

    set @iter1 = @iter1 + 1
  end

  set @Iter = @Iter + 1
end
```

But I don't think you even need the `WHILE` loops:

```
select d.*
from   defendants_ALL, #tmpFullname t1, #tmpFullname1 t2
where  d.combined_name = t1.Item + ' ' + t2.Item
```

Or (if you need to still use `LIKE`):

```
select d.*
from   defendants_ALL, #tmpFullname t1, #tmpFullname1 t2
where  d.combined_name like '%' + t1.Item + '%'
  and  d.combined_name like '%' + t2.Item + '%'
```

(All SQL is untested...)

Comment: The last works perfectly.  I was trying to complicate something and Iappreciate the help.